# Predicate format for Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm trying to understand predicates in Objective C, however I'm stuck at figuring out what the following predicate does:

```
$NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"holder.valueOfAssets > 70"];
```

Mores specifically I don't understand what the dot(.) operator does. To give some context: "holder" is a pointer to an object which has a method called "valueOfAssets".

Help is really appreciated!

Comment: It's error in Your posted code. Remove $ from beginning, it should look like this: `NSPredicate *predicate = ...`. And take a look at **Predicate Programming Guide**: http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/predicates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001789. And **NSPredicate Class Reference**: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a CoreData class Person, person has properties like name, age and child, which is a relationship to the Person class. Next you'd want to make a fetch request, grabbing some persisted Person objects, that have their child with an age equal to 18

```
NSPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat@"child.age == %@", [NSNumber numberWithInt:18]];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Person"];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
NSArray *filteredPeople = [[self managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
```

So basically the dot syntax is used to perform operations with child objects properties.